# how to convert or typecast String variable value to integer except via intval() or (int) in php

Tags: php, sql

how to convert or typecast String variable value to integer except via intval() or (int) in PHP?

i was trying to INSERT the records through INSERT INTO statement but couldn't been able to insert the values to table.

Please find the attached screenshot.

[image]

[image]

the code is here:

```
 <?php

 session_start();

 ?>

  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <HTML>
   <HEAD>

  </HEAD>
  <BODY>

  <?php

    $e = $_POST["email"];
    $p = $_POST["pass"];

    $n = $_SESSION["uname"];

    $servername= "localhost";
    $userid = "root";
    $pass="123456";
    $dbname="walleyto";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername,$userid,$pass,$dbname);

    $sql = "SELECT 
            SrNo,Name,Email,Password,Logindate,
            Logintime,Timezone,Screenwidth,Screenheight FROM login 
            WHERE Email='$e' AND Password='$p';";

    $res=$conn->query($sql);

    $logindate = Date("Y-m-d");
    $logintime = Date("h :i :s A");
    $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();

    ob_start();
    echo "<span id=demo1></span>";
    $screenwidth1 = ob_get_contents();
    $screenwidth = trim($screenwidth1);
    ob_end_clean();





         ob_start();
         echo "<span id=demo2></span>";
         $screenheight1 = ob_get_contents();
          $screenheight = trim($screenheight1);
          ob_end_clean();



            $sql1 = "INSERT INTO `login` (`SrNo`, `Name`, `Email`, 
                    `Password`, `Logindate`, `Logintime`, `Timezone`, 
                    `Screenwidth`, `Screenheight`)
                     VALUES (NULL, '$n', '$e', '$p', '$logindate', 
                    '$logintime', '$timezone', '$screenwidth', 
                    '$screenheight')";

                     $res1=$conn->query($sql1);

                     echo $sql1;
                     echo $conn->error;

                      $sql2 = "SELECT 
                        SrNo,Name,Email,Password,Logindate,Logintime,
                        Timezone,Screenwidth,Screenheight FROM login 
                        WHERE Email='$e' AND Password='$p' ORDER BY 
                        SrNo DESC;";

                        $res2 =$conn->query($sql2);


                    if($res1 == true)
                    {
                    echo " data obtained";

                    }
                   else
                    {
                    echo $conn->connect_error."Data not inserted";
                      }




                /* if($res2->num_rows>0)
                      {

                   while($row=$res2->fetch_assoc())
                       {
                       $screenwidth1 = $row["Screenwidth"];

                        }}

                      echo $screenwidth1;






                         if($res->num_rows>0)
                          {

                          $e123 = urlencode($e);
                           header("location: myprofile.php? 
                     email=$e123&screenwidth=$screenwidth1");


                        }
                       else
                        {

                         header("location: Home.php");

                            }

                     */
                     ?>

                   <script type=text/javascript>

                    var w = window.innerWidth;
                    var h = window.innerHeight;

                    var x = document.getElementById("demo1");
                    var y = document.getElementById("demo2");

                      x.innerHTML = w;
                      y.innerHTML = h;

                      </script>
                        </BODY>
                        </HTML>
```

The above code doesn't work for INSERT INTO statement as it is storing 0 values for screen width and screenheight although the javascript code is displaying 1366 and 728 values for screen width and height

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), post as text!

Comment: Please add your PHP code snippet too

Comment: Skip using primary key column also for insertion. Your query should be like `insert into login(name, email ...) values('Arvinder', ...);`

Comment: What @nice_dev said + make sure that the primary key has the AUTO_INCREMENT set.

Comment: It still adding the value 0 to screenwidth and screen height or the echo code of html in table in php myadmin

Answer (score 1):

You can Try [settype()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) function as follows:

```
settype($str, "integer");
```

Comment: It's not working. I am entering digits but settype() converts it into int(0) with the value 0